# Changing content format

Tags: linux, awk, sed, command-line, grep

I have a text file which has 1000 rows/entries. These 1000 entries correspond to the column names  for my dataframe. These are the  new features that need to be added to the dataframe  for  model development. My input text file looks like this:

```
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/3
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/4
show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g0/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/2
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/3
show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/1
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:11
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:10
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:10
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:11
formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:0#gpucores:8
```

I was looking to automatically add '' for each line, remove the line break and add a comma after each line entry. Expected  output is as follows:

```
'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/3', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/4', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g0/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/3', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/1', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:11', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:10', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:10', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:11', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:0#gpucores:8'
```

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
# if you need the space after comma
$ seq 10 | perl -pe 's/.+/"$&"/; s/\n/, / if !eof'
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"

# if space isn't required
$ seq 10 | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | paste -sd,
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"
```

Use `\x27` instead of `"` in the above solutions if you need single quote instead of double quotes

Comment: Does the advice at http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote to not use hex escape sequences `\x27` apply to perl and/or sed?

Comment: For `GNU sed` (and possibly many other implementations): `\xxx Produces or matches a character whose hexadecimal ASCII value is xx.` (it is restricted to two digits)... for perl, it requires `\x{}` form if you need more than two hex characters.. so, as far as I know, `\x27` is robust for both sed/perl... and for GNU awk - `As of version 4.2, only two digits are processed.`

Comment: good to know, thanks for the info! I tried the octal version `\047` with perl and it worked too but with sed - not so much!

Comment: `\047` in sed will be treated as `\0` (alias for `&`) followed by `47`.. you'll need `\oNNN` for octal and `\dNNN` for decimal formats

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with a shell loop. Just read the items, then print them with quotes. The only tricky thing is to print ", " after all but the last... or before all but the first (which turns out to be easier).

```
{
    read item
    printf "'%s'" "$item"
    while IFS= read -r item; do
        printf ", '%s'" "$item"
    done
    echo
} <infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

Comment: @EdMorton Those points are true in general, but I don't think relevant here. The biggest thing that slows down shell loops is creating subprocesses, and this one doesn't need to do that (I timed it at 0.05 seconds for 1,000 items on my rather old Mac). And the `read` without `-r` will mangle backslashes (although `printf` won't in this mode), but I'm pretty sure if there aren't any backslashes or quotes in the input (and if there were, they'd need special handling anyway).

Comment: @EdMorton I agree; I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s\047%s\047", sep, $0; sep=", "} END{print ""}' file
'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/3', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g2/4', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Approved#g0/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/2', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/3', 'show temperature all#Total Numbers Sent#g1/1', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:11', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:1#gpucores:10', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:10', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:2#gpucores:11', 'formulastat gpucores all parameter function-frames#formula:0#gpucores:8'
```